# GDB - Set variable without the type

Tags: c, gdb

I want to set to variables and compare them (`if $var1 == $var2`)

```
set $var1 = myvar.x
set $var2 = myvar.y
```

The type of `$var1` is different then the type of `var2` . (My binary is compiled with ICC - Intel big endian compiler)

```
var1- (struct demo * __be)
var2 -(__be struct demo *)
```

Now if i compare `$var1` to `$var2`, i get that its different although the value is the same.

Casting also doesn't work:

```
set $var2 = (struct demo *) (myvar.y)
(gdb) p $var2
$22 = (struct demo * __be) 0xabcdef
(the __be still exist)
```

How can i ignore the type ?

Comment: What are the types for `var1` and `var2`? You need to mention it clearly in your question. Use proper formatting to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `__be` is some sort of custom short cut for `__attribute__((bigendian))`, and that the native architecture is little endian, then `var1` is a structure (containing little endian values) pointer with its pointer value stored as big endian, while `var2` is a structure (containing big endian values) pointer with its pointer value stored as little endian.

I don't think there is a way to compare them directly. You will have to transform their values to the same endianess first.